# Rebooting Problems in Smartphone

Tags: reboot

my phone got dead and know even after charging it up properly its not starting and Samsung logo is appearing again and again even pressing "volume up+home button+power button "isn't helping ..
Please help I have very important data in may phone and don't want to loss it all.  my Phone Model is GT-S5282.

Comment: Can you boot into recovery? Power and Volume down? AFAIK Power and Volume Up is the Download mode.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you have some important data on phone. Using "volume up+home button+power button" combination in some phones hard resets the phone. So taking your phone to a service center is a good solution.

Comment: thanks for your opinion. but is this a sign of system crash ??

Comment: Might be or might not be. We can't tell anything until without actually seeing it. If you think its dead just take it to any authorized service center.